# Leech Lattice and Golay Code

Tags: coding-theory, integer-lattices, vector-lattices

Consider the following Miracle Octat Generator or MOG. Choose the sign $\pm 3$ and fill in the blanks $\pm 1$ to create a point $x$ in the Leech lattice $\Lambda_{24}$ with $||x||^2=8$.

$ \frac{1}{2} 
\begin{array}{|cc|cc|cc|}
\hline
 &  & 1 &  & \pm 3 &  \\
 & 1 &  & 1 &  &  \\
\hline
 &  & 1 &  &  &  \\
 &  &  & 1 &  &  \\
\hline
\end{array}
$

Not quite sure how to approach the problem. Not looking for an answer, but a sense of direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any ideas yet?